# Matplotlib: RGB colors appear black with Python 2

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib

I have a code snippet that works fine with Python 3 but doesn't with Python 2.
I'm trying to use RGB codes to define a color palette: I get the right colors with Python 3, but Python 2 show them all black...

Below is a very simple code snippet that shows this weird behavior:

```
%matplotlib inline
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pylab as plt
import numpy as np

colors = {
    'A': (234, 142, 142),
    'B': (255, 224, 137),
    'C': (189, 235, 165)}

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(20, 3), columns=list('ABC')).cumsum()

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
for col in df.columns:
    ax.plot(df.index.tolist(), df[col].values, color=(tuple(i/255 for i in colors[col])))
plt.show()
```

**Python 2**

[image: Using Python2]

**Python 3 (OK)**

[image: Using Python3]

Is that a bug or matplotlib handling RGB colors a different way on purpose? How should I adapt my code?

Software | Version
Python  | 2.7.11 64bit
IPython | 4.0.3
OS  | Windows 7 6.1.7601 SP1
matplotlib | 1.5.1

Comment: Python 2 and 3 differ in regards to the division operator. Is it possible, that your integer division is responsible -> 234/255 = 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem occurs in this line:

```
i/255 for i in colors[col]
```

It's because integer division is different in python 2 and python 3.

Python 2

```
>>> 2/3
>>> 0
```

Python 3

```
>>> 2/3
>>> 0.66...
```

To get the same behaviour in Python 2, you can use:

```
from __future__ import division
```

Comment: I was faster :-). But good answer! You could also introduce the // operator in your answer!

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you never heard of different behavior of division in python 2 and python 3. Shortly - add this to the top of your python code - `from __future__ import division`. Python 2 will correct it's unobvious behavior, and python 3 will just ignore this statement - it's already fixed.